# Listner addition and subscribtion using pubnub sdk in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am having a query related with the following:

1) where and how to add a listener, how to check if listener added or not in `laravel`.

2) process of subscription in `laravel`

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Look at your question preview under the question you're typing always make sure it's formatted in a friendly way so others can easily understand it, welcome to SO .

Comment: You would not put a "listener" (subscriber) on your server side (PHP). Only in your client side (javascript/browser app).